# Two tkinter Scrollbars conflict: the first scrolls correctly and the second does not

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, canvas, scrollbar

I have a tabcontrol where the scrollbars of Tab 2.1 and Tab 2.2 conflict.

`Tab 2.2` scrollbar scrolls vertically correctly. However, `Tab 2.1`'s scrollbar doesn't scroll.

How can I solve the problem?

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk() 
window.attributes('-zoomed', True)

style = ttk.Style(window)

tabControl = ttk.Notebook(window, style='Custom.TNotebook', width=700, height=320)
tabControl.place(x=1, y=1)

#TAB 1
main = ttk.Notebook(tabControl)
tabControl.add(main, text ='Tab 1')

#TAB 2
tab2 = ttk.Notebook(main)
main.add(tab2, text="Tab 2")

##TAB 2.1
a = ttk.Frame(tab2)
tab2.add(a, text="Tab 2.1")

canvas = tk.Canvas(a)

scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(a, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
scrollable_frame = ttk.Frame(canvas, width = 800, height = 800)

scrollable_frame.bind(
    "<Configure>",
    lambda e: canvas.configure(
        scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")
    )
)

canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=scrollable_frame, anchor="nw")
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

combo1=ttk.Combobox(scrollable_frame, width = 18)
combo1.place(x=20, y=20)
combo1['value'] = ["text1", "text2"]

canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")

##TAB 2.2
b = ttk.Frame(tab2)
tab2.add(b, text="Tab 2.2")

canvas = tk.Canvas(b)

scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(b, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
scrollable_frame = ttk.Frame(canvas, width = 800, height = 800)

scrollable_frame.bind(
    "<Configure>",
    lambda e: canvas.configure(
        scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")
    )
)

canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=scrollable_frame, anchor="nw")
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

combo1=ttk.Combobox(scrollable_frame, width = 18)
combo1.place(x=20, y=20)
combo1['value'] = ["text1", "text2"]


canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have used same variable `canvas` for the two canvases, so `canvas` inside the two binding callbacks will reference the last one (inside tab 2.2).

You can use `e.widget.master` to reference the correct *canvas* inside the two binding callbacks:

```py
scrollable_frame.bind(
    "<Configure>",
    lambda e: e.widget.master.configure(
        scrollregion=e.widget.master.bbox("all")
    )
)
```

Note that `e.widget` refers to the *`scrollable_frame`* trigger the event and so `e.widget.master` refers to the parent of that *`scrollable_frame`* which is the canvas.

Or simply use different variable names for the two canvases.

Comment: if i want to use this way, what should i in the two canvas variables? If I use canvas1 = tk.Canvas(a) and then canvas2 = tk.Canvas(b), will I need to change other things as well? (for example in canvas.create_window or in canvas.configure)

Comment: Yes you need to change other `canvas` to corresponding `canvas1` or `canvas2`.